# Code fails to print out an entire string and ends abruptly

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

```
#include "IRSensor.h"
#include "Turret.h"
#include "StepperButtonController.h"
#include "LoadBottleButton.h"

LoadBottleButton go(A3,1000);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Port Open");
}

void loop() 
{
  if(go.Read())
  {
    go.Monitor();
  }
}
```

Above is the Main code

```
#ifndef LoadBottleButton_cpp
#define LoadBottleButton_cpp

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ScaleObject.h"
#include "LoadBottleButton.h"
#include "Turret.h"
#include "StepperButtonController.h"

ScaleObject* so;
Turret* tPointer;

LoadBottleButton::LoadBottleButton(int pin, int debounce):StepperButtonController(pin,debounce)
{

}
void LoadBottleButton::Monitor()
{
  Serial.println("In Monitor");
  while(tPointer->getTurret().BottleCenterState==false)
  {
    Serial.println("In Monitor While Loop");
    tPointer->Start();
    SETUP = true;
    load = true;
    unload = !so->getScale().Empty();
    Serial.println(load);
    Serial.println(unload);
    Serial.println(!so->getScale().Empty());
    if(unload)
    {
        unload=!so->getScale().Empty();
    }
    else if(load && !so->getScale().Empty())
    {
        load = !tPointer->BottleCentered();
    }
    if(!load && !unload && SETUP)
    {
        tPointer->Stop();
        SETUP = false;
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

And above is the LoadBottleButtonClass.cpp file.

```
#ifndef Turret_cpp
#define Turret_cpp

//#include "HX711.h"
#include "Turret.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "StepperButtonController.h"
#include "ScaleObject.h"
#include "IRSensor.h"

//StepperButtonController Clear(9,1000);

void StepTurret();
Turret turret(2,3,4,StepTurret);
void StepTurret()
{
  turret.Step();
}

ScaleObject* tso;
IRSensor* irs;

Turret::Turret()
{

}
Turret Turret::getTurret()
{
  return turret;
}
Turret::Turret(int en, int dir, int clk, void(*stepFunction)()):stepper2(en,dir,clk,stepFunction)
{
  tso->getScale().tare();
  tso->getScale().set_gain(128);
  tso->getScale().set_scale(-3483.4);
}
void Turret::SeekBottleCenter()
{
  Start();
  while(irs->IRState()==1)
  {
    Serial.println("High");
    Serial.println(irs->IRState());
  }
  while(irs->IRState()==0)
  {
    Serial.println("Low");
  }     
}
bool Turret::BottleCentered()
{
  return turret.BottleCenterState;
}
void Turret::ClearFunction()
{
  wt = tso->getScale().get_units();
  while(wt>5)
  {
    Serial.println("Clearing");
    wt = tso->getScale().get_units();
    Rotate(20);
  }
}
#endif
```

And above is the Turret.cpp file.

```
#ifndef IRSensor_cpp
#define IRSensor_cpp

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "IRSensor.h"
IRSensor i(5);
IRSensor::IRSensor(int pin)
{
  IRSensorPin = pin;
  pinMode(pin,INPUT);
}
int IRSensor::IRState()
{
  return digitalRead(i.IRSensorPin);
}
#endif
```

And above is the `IRSensor.cpp` file. So essentially I press the go button declared in my `main`, that button calls monitor in the `LoadBottleButton.cpp` file, that method uses a turret point to get access to the `Turret.cpp`  methods and a `boolean` named `BottleCenterState`. But the code only gets so far, it stops after printing "`In`" of the `Serial.println("In Monitor")` line. Why is that?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the minimal code needed to replicate your problem. When doing that it's a good chance you might even figure it out yourself. And if not, starting over from a simple base, and then step by step adding features and functionality, testing every step along the way, usually helps making code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't count on the output to tell you where the error is. That serial print may have completed successfully and the message is buffered in an output stream waiting for a chance to be written to the serial port.

A much more likely cause of the crash is the line below the serial print.

```
Serial.println("In Monitor");
while(tPointer->getTurret().BottleCenterState==false)
```

`tPointer` is used and I don't see anywhere in the provided code it is assigned a valid, dereferencable pointer. Dereferencing an undefined pointer results in undefined behaviour, and in this case probably a crash. Even if it isn't the crash you are seeing, this is almost certainly wrong.

How to fix it?

From the code provided it doesn't look like `tpointer` needs to be a pointer at all.

```
Turret turret;
```

May be all you need. Allocating `turret` statically eliminates the possibility of pointer and memory management bugs and reduces the chance of leaks.

Otherwise,

```
Turret* tPointer = new Turret();
```

But this leaves you with the problem of how and when do you `delete tPointer;`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your string doesn't contain a `NULL` character. This will terminate the string abruptly.